# heap corruption when deleting array pointer C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, heap-memory

So, I'm getting a heap corruption error in the Expand method for an Ordered List Class I'm working on. The expand method is called when the client tries to Insert() a new item into the list, and there isn't currently room left in the array. When I take the delete line out, the program runs fine, but I know I have an inaccessible object each time it expands. However, when I put the delete line in, the program explodes at run-time.

Additionally, this only happens in my Expand() method. It doesn't do this in my Contract() method, which is called each time there is a deletion from the list that brings the number of list elements down below 1/4 the total space currently available, it cuts the size in half. I can delete the old list in this method without any problems.

GetListPtr(), SetListPtr(), and GetLength() are all inherited from a ListClass object, which I received in the form of a header file and object code, so I'm not sure exactly how they work. ItemType is a struct, only containing an integer field, key.

I've read a number of questions on here already and didn't find any that seemed to provide any help in regards to my situation.

```
void OrdListClass::Expand()
{
    ItemType* newList = new ItemType[size * 2];
    ItemType* temp = GetListPtr();

    size = size * 2;

    // Copy the current list to the new list.
    for(int i = 0; i < GetLength(); i++)
        newList[i] = temp[i];

    // Point to the new list.
    SetListPtr(newList);

    // Delete the old list
    delete temp;  <-- This line

    // Reset the pointers
    temp = nullptr;
    newList = nullptr;
}


void OrdListClass::Contract()
{
    ItemType* newList = new ItemType[size / 2];
    ItemType* temp = GetListPtr();

    size = size / 2;

    // Copy the old list into the new one
    for(int i = 0; i < GetLength(); i++)
        newList[i] = temp[i];

    // Set the list pointer to point to the new list
    SetListPtr(newList);

    // Delete the old list
    delete temp;

    temp = nullptr;
    newList = nullptr;
}
```

Thanks again for reading this, any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `GetLength()` use `size` at all?

Comment: Also, if you allocate with `new[]` then you need to use `delete[]`.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious, `GetListPtr()` and `GetLength()` are paramount to how this function works, and it is a modest understatement to say that your decision to *not* include them is .. inconvenient. Particularly in light of Mr.Ninja's still-unanswered question.

Comment: Sorry for the very delayed response, I was up all night working on this program and ended up falling asleep before I saw any responses. In regards to GetListPtr(), it was inherited along with SetListPtr() and GetLength() from a ListClass object, which was given to me in the form of a header file and the object code, so i don't know exactly how Get/SetListPtr() work, but I know GetLength() returns the current number of elements in the list. The size variable holds the current size of the array, or max elements it can hold.

Comment: So, as an example, you have no idea if `SetListPtr` deletes the old pointer for you or not.  Seems it's time to have a talk with whoever you got this code from.

Comment: Thats understandable. I actually emailed them explaining my problem, and have yet to get a response. Maybe this is something I should post in a separate question, but while I've been working on debugging, I discovered that if I wrap the Expand() code in any sort of programming structure, such as executing it within an if block or wrapping it in a try/catch, it throws the Heap corruption error, but if i remove the code around it, the error is not thrown. I guess what I'm wondering is why this could happen in a general, not necessarily in my specific case.

Comment: Heap corruption is always hard to track down as when you get the error might not be when it actually happened, it's just when it was noticed.  The corruption could be happening in completely unrelated code and you just happen to get the error here.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your list was allocated with:

```
ItemType* newList = new ItemType[size * 2];
```

If that's the case, you need to do:

```
delete[] temp;
```

Elements allocated with `new[]`, need to be deleted with `delete[]`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/

Comment: Thank you, I actually tried both and neither work in my Expand() method, but both work in my Contract() method.